# Общий фон на несколько блоков

Tags: html, css

На странице есть 2 блока div, идут друг за другом, нужно поставить общий фон для этих блоков, т.е одну цельную картинку, попробовал таким образом

```
.welcome, .welcome__progress {
background-image: url('../img/bg1.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Но на 2ом блоке эта же картинка дублируется, а не продолжает ту, которая на 1ом блоке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.block {
  border:1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
}

.welcome,
.welcome__progress {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/458/354?gravity=east');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed; /* !!! */
}
```

```html
<div class="block welcome"></div>
<div class="block welcome__progress"></div>
```

> добавить еще 1 задний фон, но только на первый блок, поверх другого

```css
.block {
  border:1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
}
.block div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.sm.png');
  opacity:0.5;
}

.welcome,
.welcome__progress {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/458/354?gravity=east');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed; /* !!! */
}
```

```html
<div class="block welcome"><div></div></div>
<div class="block welcome__progress"></div>
```

Comment: идеально! Спасибо! А еще вопрос один, можно как-то добавить еще 1 задний фон, но только на первый блок, поверх другого

Comment: @Ayurpwnz Можно, но для этого в первом блоке нужен еще один элемент - смотрите второй пример.

Comment: Буду разбираться, спасибо.

Comment: Немного не получается, видно, что фон добавляется, т.к текст съезжает, но он находится на заднем фоне, не получается переместить на передний

Comment: @Ayurpwnz Мне трудно понять, что присходит. Задайте еще один вопрос с примером.

Comment: Создал, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/919775/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%85-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be