# Добавление заднего фона, поверх другого

Tags: html, css

Чтобы было понятнее [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/919756/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2) на вопрос пред идущий...

Не получается добавить еще 1 `background` поверх другого на блок

```
<div class="welcome" id="welcome" >
```

```css
.welcome,
.welcome__progress {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/458/354?gravity=east');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.bg2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/1.sm.png');
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.welcome {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #0E1125;
}

.welcome__inner {
  padding-top: 250px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 815px;
  max-width: 1248px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.welcome__left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.welcome__left>h1 {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #FFF;
}

.welcome__left>p {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 42px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #C1CBE0;
}

.welcome__left>.btn {
  margin-top: 40px;
  align-self: flex-start;
  color: #fff;
}

.welcome__right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.welcome__countdown {
  align-self: center;
  display: flex;
}

.welcome__countdown-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.welcome__countdown>.welcome__countdown-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.welcome__countdown-item-value {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #3579FF;
}

.welcome__countdown-item-title {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}

.welcome__info {
  margin-top: 60px;
  align-self: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.welcome__info-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.welcome__info>.welcome__info-item:not(:nth-child(even)) {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.welcome__info-item-title {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
}

.welcome__info-item-block {
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 20px;
  /* border: 1px solid #fff; */
  /* box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(48, 43, 99, 0.5); */
  width: 240px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.welcome__progress {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #0E1125;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* PROGRESS START */

.progress {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 1208px;
  width: 100%;
  align-self: center;
  padding-right: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.progress__bar {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1239px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  height: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px rgba(48, 43, 99, 0.3);
}

.progress__bar-indicator {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff 40%, #3579FF 50%);
}

.progress__caps {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.progress__cap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.progress__cap-value {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-40px);
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: flex;
  user-select: none;
}

.progress__cap-value>span {
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: block;
}

.progress__cap-plank {
  height: 20px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #222;
}

.progress__cap-title {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(40px);
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
}

.progress__cap-title>span {
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: block;
}

.progress__cap-title--green {
  color: #3579FF;
}

@media (max-width: 1599px) {
  .progress {
    max-width: 900px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="welcome" id="welcome">
  <div class="bg2"></div>
  <div class="welcome__inner">
    <div class="welcome__left">
      <h1>text</h1>
      <p style="font-size:20px">text</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn" style="position:absolute; margin-left:980px;margin-top:410px">Whitepapper</a>
    </div>
    <div class="welcome__right">
      <div class="welcome__countdown">
        <div class="welcome__countdown-item">
          <div class="welcome__countdown-item-value" id="endDays">00</div>
          <div class="welcome__countdown-item-title">Days</div>
        </div>
        <div class="welcome__countdown-item">
          <div class="welcome__countdown-item-value" id="endHours">00</div>
          <div class="welcome__countdown-item-title">Hours</div>
        </div>
        <div class="welcome__countdown-item">
          <div class="welcome__countdown-item-value" id="endMinutes">00</div>
          <div class="welcome__countdown-item-title">Minutes</div>
        </div>
        <div class="welcome__countdown-item">
          <div class="welcome__countdown-item-value" id="endSeconds">00</div>
          <div class="welcome__countdown-item-title">Seconds</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="welcome__info">
        <div class="welcome__info-item">
          <div class="welcome__info-item-title">text</div>
          <div class="welcome__info-item-block">text</div>
        </div>
        <div class="welcome__info-item">
          <div class="welcome__info-item-title">text</div>
          <div class="welcome__info-item-block">text</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="welcome__progress">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress__caps">
      <div class="progress__cap">
        <div class="progress__cap-value">0</div>
        <div class="progress__cap-plank"></div>
        <div class="progress__cap-title"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress__cap">
        <div class="progress__cap-value">2 <span>000</span></div>
        <div class="progress__cap-plank"></div>
        <div class="progress__cap-title progress__cap-title--green">Soft<span>Cap</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress__cap">
        <div class="progress__cap-value">4 <span>000</span></div>
        <div class="progress__cap-plank"></div>
        <div class="progress__cap-title"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress__cap">
        <div class="progress__cap-value">6 <span>000</span></div>
        <div class="progress__cap-plank"></div>
        <div class="progress__cap-title"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress__cap">
        <div class="progress__cap-value">8 <span>000</span> </div>
        <div class="progress__cap-plank"></div>
        <div class="progress__cap-title"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress__cap">
        <div class="progress__cap-value">10000 <span>text</span> </div>
        <div class="progress__cap-plank"></div>
        <div class="progress__cap-title">Hard<span>text</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress__bar">
      <div class="progress__bar-indicator" style="width: 55.8%"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: У вас одинаковый фон на двух блоках .welcome, .welcome__progress удалите  , .welcome__progress из css если я правильно вас понял

Comment: Можешь разъяснить, что это означает ***Не получается добавить еще 1 background поверх другого на блок***?

Comment: Особенно интересует часть  ***поверх другого на блок***

Comment: @Air это продолжение вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/919756

Comment: @Igor, ща понял...)))  Хотя бы ссылку дал бы на свой пред идущий вопрос...

Comment: @Igor, хотя не совсем понятно какого конечного результата хочет добиться автор...

Comment: @Igor знаете как поправить?

Comment: @Ayurpwnz У `.bg2` нулевая высота - не понимаю, почему. Поэтому его не видно.

Comment: @Igor точно, теперь оторабажается, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю из комментариев, блок не отображается из-за того, что у него нулевая высота. Смотрите в вашем HTML .bg2 это дочерний элемент .welcome, в стилях вы указываете ему высоту в процентах, это означает что он берет высоту родительского элемента и отсчитывает от нее свою высоту, так вот в вашем коде у .welcome высота не задана, ему не от чего считать. Обозначьте высоту для .welcome и все заработает, только не в процентах:).